# What is the Jacobian of the following function

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-derivative, matrix-equations

Consider a function F: $R^n \to R^n$ defined by
$$f(u) = A*u*(n+1)+\lambda *B$$

Where A is a tridiagonal n-by-n matrix with -2 on the main diagonal and 1 on the off diagonals.
B = $\begin{pmatrix} { e }^{ { u }_{ 1 } } \\ ... \\ { e }^{ { u }_{ n } } \end{pmatrix}$

What is the Jacobian of F?

Comment: It is the matrix consisting of partial derivatives of components of $F$ with respect to its parameters.

Comment: Yes i know that but I am unable to derive it. Could you tell me how to do so? Differentiation on matrices is something I do not understand how to proceed with.

Comment: Write out each component as a scalar-valued function, then find its gradient. Put each gradient as a row vector and stack them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\nabla f = A(n+1)+\lambda \mathrm{diag}(e^{u_1},e^{u_2},...,e^{u_n})$. ($\mathrm{diag}$ is building a diagonal matrix, with the diagonal elements given in the brackets)